# Getting an error Elasticache snapshot not ready when exporting to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-elasticache

- I am trying to write a bash script to automatically store elasticache snapshots to s3 via cron job running inside Amazon Linux 2 on an AWS EC2 instance

When I ran the code below, it gives me an error saying the snapshot is not ready

```
#!/bin/sh

cache_cluster_id="test-elasticache-001"
current_time="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")";
file_name="test-elasticache-${current_time}";
max_number_of_backups_to_keep=8;

snapshot_status=$(aws elasticache create-snapshot --cache-cluster-id $cache_cluster_id --snapshot-name $file_name);
echo $snapshot_status;
export_status=$(aws elasticache copy-snapshot --source-snapshot-name $file_name --target-snapshot-name $file_name --target-bucket test-elasticache-manual-backups);
echo $export_status;

# https://gist.github.com/luckyjajj/463b98e5ec8127b21c6b
# Check if number of stored backups is 8
if [ $(aws elasticache describe-snapshots --cache-cluster-id $cache_cluster_id |grep SnapshotName | wc -l)  = "$max_number_of_backups_to_keep" ]; then
    # Get the name of the oldest snapshot
    old_snapshot="$(aws elasticache describe-snapshots --cache-cluster-id $cache_cluster_id |grep SnapshotName | head -1 | cut -d \" -f 4)"
    aws elasticache delete-snapshot --snapshot-name $old_snapshot
fi
```

How do I wait for the snapshot to be ready and then export it to S3?

Comment: You can use `describe-snapshots` to get the status. Poll for it in a loop until status is `available`.

Answer (score 0):

To provide you with accurate help, more information regarding your Elasticache Redis cluster is needed:

- Could you please specify if you are using Cluster Mode Enabled (CME) or Cluster Mode Disabled (CMD)?
- Which version of Redis are you currently utilizing?
- Which type of engine you are using?
- etc.

In the meantime, you may find the following documentation resources useful:

- [Backups Constraints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups.html#backups-constraints)
- [Scheduling automatic backups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups-automatic.html)

Comment: cluster mode disabled, redis latest 7.0, not sure what you mean by engine type